# Proof verification that every open set consists of countably many open intervals

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Hi I encountered this problem in Analysis 1 from Otto Forster. I know that there exist answers already concerning this question, but I came up with a proof and am not sure whether the proof is valid or not, if it is not valid, I'm very curious as to why is it not valid. The problem is stated below:

A subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ is called open, if to every $a\in U$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ so that

$$]a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon[ \subset U $$

And we were asked to show that every open subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ is an union of countably many open intervals.

The definition that this book uses: For any set $A$, $A$ is called countable if there exists a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$

I argued:

$U$ must be an union of open intervals, suppose it is not, then $U$ must contain some $u$ that there exists no $\epsilon > 0$ so that $]u-\epsilon,u+\epsilon[\subset U $, a contradiction to the definition of $U$.

First we show that for any open subset $U$, we can describe it with non-overlapping open intervals, in other words, it is the union of open intervals but none of them overlaps.

Suppose two open intervals $i=]a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon[$ and $j=]b-\epsilon',b+\epsilon'[$ overlap, w.l.o.g  $a<b$,if they overlap "partly", we have 
$$a-\epsilon<a<b-\epsilon'<a+\epsilon<b<b+\epsilon'$$

we can then form a new interval by taking their midpoint. Also if $j$ is included within $i$, we can just throw away $j$.

Suppose $U$ is not empty, if it's empty then the statement holds vacuously. Then we pick some $u\in U$.
So now let $U$ consists of non-overlapping open intervals, we can then pick an unique open interval $T$ so that $u\in T$, now we define $F$ to be the set of the intervals and a function $f:F\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ with

$$f(S) = x,\;\;x\;is\;the\; rational\; number\; with \;the \;smallest\; dividend\;within \;S $$

Since the intervals are non-overlapping, $f$ is an injection.

Now we define $g:\mathbb{Q}\longrightarrow F$ as following:
$$g(x) = S\;\;\;\; \;if\; f(S)=x$$

otherwise,
$$g(x) = T$$

So that $g$ is a surjection (onto). Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, let $h:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ be a surjection, so that $g \circ h:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow F$ is also a surjection. Therefore $F$ is countable.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to see something at the start explaining why we can assume that $U$ is a union of open intervals (it's simple, but you should probably spell it out).

Comment: @user3482749 Done! Is it correct that way?

Comment: The big problem I see is that you only show how to merge two overlapping intervals at a time, but repeating that process isn't necessarily going to finish after a finite number of combinations.  For example, what if you start with $U = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} ]n-1, n+1[$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes! That's exactly why I'm unsure if the proof is valid. Do you mind to tell me how to cover this hole in the proof? Should we say that we merge all overlapping intervals in the same time (keep going if the next interval still overlaps) instead of doing them one by one?

Comment: The usual way is to "cut straight to the finish" and for each $x \in U$, define $a(x) = \inf \{ a \mid ]a, x] \subseteq U \}$ and $b(x) = \sup \{ b \mid [x, b[ \subseteq U \}$.  Then the open intervals $]a(x), b(x)[$ form the disjoint open intervals which make up $U$.  (Keeping in mind that for some $x$, it's possible that $a(x) = -\infty$ and/or $b(x) = +\infty$.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler I see, that's a very good one! But what do we need to say about the choice of $x$, should we start with choosing an arbitrary $x\in U$ and then pick  $y\in U$ with $y>b(x)$? (assuming $b(x)<\infty $ ) And also similarly we pick another $y\in U$ with $y<a(x)$. Will this choice of $x,y$ work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The point is that you can prove $\{ ]a(x), b(x)[ \mid x \in U \}$ forms a partition of $U$ into disjoint open intervals.  In other words, if $x, y \in U$, then the two intervals $]a(x), b(x)[$ and $]a(y), b(y)[$ are either equal or disjoint.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I understand now, thank you very much! This question is pretty much answered, should I answer my own question by saying that the question is answered in the comment?